# Python Generic optional param

Tags: python, oop, generics, fastapi, pydantic

I have `class CRUDBase` (absolutely same as [tiangolo example](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/crud/base.py)) and a lot of classes that inherited this Base class.

And i want to add optional schema to this class: (this option does not work)

```py
class CRUDBase(Generic[ModelType, CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType, Optional[ValidateSchemaType]=None]):
```

to do functions like that:

```py
def validate(self, db_obj):
    if ValidateSchemaType is None:
        raise NotImplementedError
    try:
        ValidateSchemaType.from_orm(db_obj)
    except ValidationError as e:
        return translate_error(e)
    return {}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think you are supposed to use [type variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) with [Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic). It is not clear to me what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add argument `validation_schema` in your `__init__` method:

```py
def __init__(self,model: Type[ModelType], *, validation_schema=None):
    self.model = model
    self.validation_schema = validation_schema
```

And successful create your validation method in base class:

```py
def validate(self, *, db_obj: Optional[ModelType] = None, **kwargs):
    if self.validation_schema is None:
        raise NotImplementedError("The schema was not passed when creating the class")
    try:
        if db_obj:
            self.validation_schema.from_orm(db_obj)
        else:
            self.validation_schema(**kwargs)
    except ValidationError as e:
        raise e
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix work with model and validation. I think it's not good idea. You should add validation to you Pydantic schema like this

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class BaseValidator(BaseModel):
    def validate_db_object(self, db_obj):
        return self.validate(db_obj)


class User(BaseValidator):
    id: int
    name = 'John Doe'
    signup_ts: Optional[datetime] = None
    friends: List[int] = []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = User(id=1, name='Egor')
    a.validate_db_object(db_obj={'id': 5})
```